# Rails pass array to partial using collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, slim-lang

I'm trying to iterate through a regular array (not ActiveRecord), and render a partial using each element.

In my view (I'm using slim):

```
== render partial: "layouts/display_elements", collection: my_array
```

My partial (for now) only contains:

```
= "#{display_element}"
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `display_element' for #<#<Class:0x007f7fe2e6ca58>:0x007f7fe51e0408>
```

Is this a limit of imposed by not using ActiveRecord? Do I have to resort to

```
= my_array.each do |e|
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not very familiar with the slim-lang, but I think adding the `:as` option will work for you:

```
== render partial: "layouts/display_elements", collection: my_array, as: :display_element
```

This will allow you to access the collection `my_array` as the `display_item` local variable within your partial.